# Change the aspect ratio (with pbaspect) for a plotyy in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to change the aspect ratio of a `plotyy` figure in Matlab. `pbaspect` only changes the `gca` which is only one of the two axis in `plotyy`. So is there a way to get both axes of the `plotyy` changed? Thanks Maarten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify the axes handles:

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(...)
pbaspect(AX(1),...) % set aspect ratio of the first axis
pbaspect(AX(2),...) % set aspect ratio of the second axis
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect. I tried a few things except this obvious one.